# Using VbScript to find a string in a column and return the line values

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use the VBScript to find a string in a column in a MySql database, and return all the values in that line.

So I have a schema called machine12, a table called recipe_list, a column called recipe_name and a string value called RecipeName.

I want to be able to lookup in the MySql table and return the recipe settings for the recipe name.

I can't figure out how to find the return the settings using a string....

I can do it using the line ID with the following script:

```
Dim sql, numRow, StartOffset
sql="Select * FROM machine12.`recipe_list`Where ID="&$RecipeValue&""
$numCur=$DBCursorOpenSQL("MySqlDB",sql)
numRow=$DBCursorRowCount($numCur)
$globaldata_CurrentRecipe.ID=$DBCursorGetValue($numCur," id")
```

I think the code should look like:

```
Dim sql, numRow, StartOffset
sql="Select * FROM machine12.`recipe_list`Where recipe_name="&$RecipeName&""
$numCur=$DBCursorOpenSQL("MySqlDB",sql)
numRow=$DBCursorRowCount($numCur)
```

But that doesn't work..

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the ticks:

Dim sql
sql="Select * FROM machine12.recipe_list Where recipe_name = '" & $RecipeName & "'"